# JAXB @XmlAnyElement ignoring CDATA

Tags: xml, jaxb, cdata

Our application was working fine till I encountered CDATA section in incoming xml. I know CDATA in xml is quite common case. Some how we forgot about it. We are using JAXB mapping in the following way

```
@XmlRootElement(name="MyRoot")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyRoot {

    @XmlElement(name="One")
    private String one;

    @XmlElement(name="Three")
    private String three;

    @XmlAnyElement
    private List<Object> remaining = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public MyRoot() {
    }
}
```

I receive the following xml from another application. I really didn't understand why JAXB is ignoring CDATA in /MyRoot/Two/bla2/one. After transformation I see output like this `<Two><bla><bla> <bla2><one>  function matchwo(a,b) { if (a < b && a < 0) then { return 1;} else { return 0;}} </one></bla2> <Two>` (notice there is no CDATA)

## Here is XML

```
<MyRoot>
<One></One>
<Two>
    <bla></bla>
    <bla2><one><![CDATA[  function matchwo(a,b) { if (a < b && a < 0) then { return 1;} else { return 0;}} ]]></one></bla2>
</Two>
<Three></Three>
<Four>some text</Four>
```

Please help me to understand the issue. Am I missing anything for CDATA?  Thanks in advance.